# Python word counter program

Tags: python

I'm getting the error below when the program executes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Downloads/Py/file.py", line 41, in <module>
    sentences_list = get_sentences(file_name)
  File "C:/Users/User/Downloads/Py/file.py", line 13, in get_sentences
    sentences_list.remove('')
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

The program is supposed to count the number of sentences, words, and unique words. As you input or after

Reading "speech.txt", count the sentences (they end with periods) then

Count the words. To distinguish words, you may want to remove all punctuation and control characters: for example commas, periods, and newlines and also limit unique words, convert all letters to lower case, split the text into a list of words, and sort the list alphabetically to assist counting speech.txt can have any random number of words.

Example Output :

```
Speech Analysis:
Sentences = 11
Words = 260
Unique words = 142
```

Here is the Python code snippet :

```
sentences_list = message.split('.')
sentences_list.remove('')
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you do `sentences_list.remove('')`?

Comment: Try `sentences_list = list(filter(None,sentences_list))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.remove(x) will raise value error if x is not found in list.
What you can do is - print the list before removing ('') from the list to see if it's in the list or not.

Another thing that you should do is error/exception handling

```
try:
    sentences_list.remove('')
except ValueError as e:
    print("('') not in sentence list")
    pass # or do something else here
```